# I want to create a view with filters filters

Tags: views

I want to create a view with Better Exposed filters, filters exactly like in 
http://www.shopmgd.com/gold-jewellery.html. I am new to drupal, so somebody please help How can i do dis? I am using drupal 7.

Comment: Check out this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2JP0_CxW1_I it should get you going.

Comment: I had tried the tutorial before, my problem is i'm struggling to bring format options in one block region(sidebar) and the formatted display in content region. can you please help me out

Comment: You need to expose your filters in a block and place it in a region, check out this tutorial http://s1l.org/views-3-exposed-filters-block You should edit your question also as you don't really specify what you need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how to close this question but I'll add my comments as answer so that Jumma can approve and close it.

You need to expose your filters using the Better Exposed filters module, see [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2JP0_CxW1_I).

To place your exposed filter in one region and the result of the view in another region you need to expose your filters in a block. See [this tutorial](http://s1l.org/views-3-exposed-filters-block) learn how to do that.